# Run a ReactJS build by webpack on JSF/XHTML

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, jsf, babeljs

I'm trying to make some innovations on this big JSF-javaBackend app we have

So I am working with ReactJS and thinking why not both. So far I can call the reactJS library and print some small component, also the same logic using JSX. And both of them work just fine

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" >
    <h:head>
        <title>Test React JSF</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../../../../resources/Adamantium/adamantium-layout/css/font-awesome.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../../../../resources/css/style.css"/>

        <link  rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" href="./static/css/main.1ab75c23.chunk.css"/> 


    </h:head>

    <h:body   > 


        <h2>  React vanilla </h2> 

        <!-- We will put our React component inside this div. -->
        <div id="like_button_container"></div>

        <!-- Load React. -->
        <!-- Note: when deploying, replace "development.js" with "production.min.js". -->
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"  ></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"  ></script>

        <!-- Don't use this in production: --> 
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Load our React component. -->
        <script src="like_button.js"></script>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>

        <h2>  JSX </h2> 
        <div id="babel"></div>
        <script type="text/babel">

            ReactDOM.render(
            <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
            document.getElementById('babel')
            );

        </script>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>


        <script src="./static/js/1.6105a37c.chunk.js" type="application/javascript" ></script>
        <script src="./static/js/main.7bbc540b.chunk.js" type="application/javascript" ></script>

        <h2>  React JSXs Bundles </h2> 

        <div id="root"></div>


    </h:body>
</html>
```

My problem starts when I try to use something a little bit more complex, which is a  build with babel create-react-app (`npm run build`) which prints nothing, no errors, no warnings, no weblogic fail on parsing, just do nothing. I have experience with both frameworks but I can't merge them even for a dumb component (no state component)

I suspect of XHTML trying to read my bundled react app not as a JavaScript file, but it should have been fixed with the `"type="application/javascript"` tag.

I will leave here the like button, the JSX and vanilla react are examples from the react docs

```
   'use strict';
const e = React.createElement;
class LikeButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { liked: false };
  }
  render() {
    if (this.state.liked) {
      return 'You liked this.';
    }
    return e(
      'button',
      { onClick: () => this.setState({ liked: true }) },
      'Like'
    );
  }
}
const domContainer = document.querySelector('#like_button_container');
ReactDOM.render(e(LikeButton), domContainer);
```

Comment: Sorry, help me understand.  Your `like_button` component isn't rendering?

Comment: like_button is working fine but, JSX bunldes does not. Like button is a simple JS using react lib, and bunlde (1.6105a37c.chunk.js) is the npm run build from a create react app. That bundle is not rendering the react code into <div id=root ></div>